# Area of one leaft of Rose curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Evaluation of shaded  area of leaf of curve $r=\cos(2\theta)$

[image]

What i try: Area of leaf of curve

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\beta}_{\alpha}r^2d\theta$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int^{\frac{3\pi}{4}}_{\frac{5\pi}{4}}\cos^2(2\theta)d\theta=\frac{1}{4}\int^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}2\cos^2(2\theta)d\theta$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}\int^{\frac{5\pi}{4}}_{\frac{3\pi}{4}}\bigg(1+\cos(4\theta)\bigg)d\theta=\frac{\pi}{8}$$
Can anyone please tell me is my process is right and also tell me is my upper and lower limit is right or not.  If not Then please correct me. Thanks

Comment: Your final limits are correct, you have interchanged the limits at one step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but you can use different bounds for the integral:

Since $\cos x = \cos(x + 2\pi)$, $\cos(2x) = \cos(2x + 2\pi) = \cos \big(2(x + \pi) \big)$. Therefore, substituting $u = x + \pi$ or $x = u - \pi$ gives:

$$\frac{1}{2}\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{- \frac{\pi}{4}}\cos^2(2u) \ du=\frac{1}{4}\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}2\cos^2(2u)\ du$$

$$=\frac{1}{4}\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}\bigg(1+\cos(4u)\bigg) \ du=\frac{\pi}{8}$$